# Float value suddenly becoming huge

Tags: c, floating-point

I would rather not dump code, but explain my problem. After hours of debugging I managed to understand that at some point in my code, a float value that **is not explicitly modified** turns HUGE (more than 1e15). I do use a lot of memory in my program (a string array containing 800+ words), other than that though, I have no idea what could cause this.

If anyone has any ideas regarding this, please share. Otherwise, I'll post a pastebin of the 
code soon.

**EDIT:** 
Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/vgiZweNq. The problem rests in the `next_generation()` function, where the `sumfit` variable goes nuts at random times in the loop.

Also, I've compiled this on linux using `-fno-stack-limit` and `-fstack-check`, to avoid stack overflows.

**EDIT 2:**
I've changed the program to use a dynamically allocated linked list, to further avoid stack overflows. Still, `sumfit` gets changed to Floatzilla at random points, usually pretty early on.

Cheers!

Comment: If you don’t explicitly touch the variable, our best guess would be some memory management bug. Post the code, the crystal ball is hazy today.

Comment: Share the code, please. Try to boil it down to the part where the `float` catches hugitis.

Comment: Your error is due to a bug, somewhere, most likely a buffer overrun.  Run your code through Valgrind.

Comment: Use a data breakpoint to get the debugger to break when it gets modified.

Comment: @Hans - agreed, data breakpoint is definitely the best way to track this sort of thing down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using strcpy on the chrom array, but i don't see where they ever get null terminated.

Maybe I'm just missing it, though.

Answer (score 2):

Since the variable is obviously being modified from an unexpected point, you might want to check some possibilities:

- Is it being modified from a different thread or from an interrupt / event handler? If so, is the access properly synchronized to prevent a data race?
- Are you doing pointer arithmetic that might be buggy and cause access outside the intended buffer?
- Are you casting pointers between types of different sizes?
- Especially if you are working on an embedded device: Maybe the memory is full and your stack is overlapping the heap, or the global variables.

More information about the platform this happens on would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a huge string array. I reckon you're probably going off the end of it. Keep track of the size of data going into that array.